# ng-repeat running on state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a strange issue in angular and ionic. I have the "ifPostExcluded" being called again when exiting to another state.

This is also being called when the repeater has finished loading (notice I have my own directive "on-finish-render") to detect this.

```
<div ng-repeat="post in postList" on-finish-render="ngRepeatFinished">
    <div class="{{post.id}}" ng-if="post.cat.length > 0">
        <div class="w-col w-col-4 push-block-wrap" ng-if="ifPostExcluded(post.cat, post.id)">
            <div ng-include src="'templates/_loop.html'"></div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

I am puzzled as to why this is happening. I found [this neat solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30986544/angular-ng-repeat-cache-avoid-re-rendering-on-state-change) but before I implement it I would rather try to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried with a `collection-repeat` ?

Comment: @e666 good point will try to see I it makes a difference

Comment: @e666 this did not work. I will have to debug this deeply but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for those who are having a similar issue, I solved it by using one time binding as per this post.
[AngularJs alternative to ng-if to save digest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37559451/angularjs-alternative-to-ng-if-to-save-digest)